# Laravel 5.3 Is safe remove/delete storage folder from Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-5.3, storagefolder

I have a Laravel 5.3 project versioned, and files in this folder are constantly changing.

Is safe to remove from version control system?

If I delete that folder from my working copy, Laravel can keep working?

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsyw9.png)

Comment: no do not delete. you can miss old version files or you can not update next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll notice in a default Laravel 5.3 install there are 3 folders within `storage`. It looks like this:

```
+ storage
    + app
    + framework
    + logs
```

And each of those subfolders has a `.gitignore` as well as other folders (also usually with `gitignores`. Those `.gitignore` files generally say to ignore all files except for the `.gitignore`. For example, this is the `.gitignore` inside `storage/logs`:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

That means that you can keep this in version control, but any file written to that folder (except for the `.gitignore` file itself) will NOT be in your git repository.

Also, it might help to know that these folders have a specific purpose:

`app`: Designed to be used as storage for files outside of your root public folder

`framework`: By defaut, this is where Laravel writes a lot of its files for cache and views

`logs`: Where the error logs are written

If you delete the root `storage` folder or these subfolders, the framework will have trouble finding these files and you'll get errors.

Comment: Laravel also need the subfolders in the `framework` folder : `cache`, `sessions` and `views`. So you should put the `!.gitignore` in each of the subfolder instead of the `framework` folder.

Comment: Laravel does all of this by default. There's no need to overthink this.

Comment: What happens is that my boss uses SVN :(

I miss Git. 
I'll break stackoverflow rules just to thank you!! Very detailed answer!!! :D